# Modifying the active class and grabbing the updated data using Beautiful Soup/Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get the data new data whenever the active class of a website changes, I tried placing 'active' in one of the classes I want the data on but the data doesn't seem to change. It just remains the same.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(overview.text, 'lxml')
raw_data = temp_soup.find('nav', class_='season-selector')
season_list = raw_data.findAll('a')

for item in season_list:
    item['class'] = 'active'
```

I think that this is because it did not update. This came to the conclusion that maybe it's not BeautifulSoup that I should be tinkering with. It should be requests, although I am not sure. How do I change the active class using requests? Or am I missing something with BeautifulSoup?

This is the data I would like to change my active class on, if the active class is not selected the class is simply just empty.

```
<ul data-v-185d57a5="">
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="active">All Acts</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E3: A1</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E2: A3</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E2: A2</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E2: A1</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E1: A3</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E1: A2</a>
 <a data-v-e398f038="" data-v-185d57a5="" class="">E1: A1</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show your code and output/error in text so we can better help you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post minimal example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've added in my code, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @julianbuckham When I run your code _all_ of the classes do change to `active`. I'm using the HTML snippet you provided. Can you share the URL? maybe the data is loaded dynamically

Comment: @MendelG, here is the URL that I am using. https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/KRPX%20%20fancybaby%23WTB

Comment: Could you explain what the aim is a bit better. The items you are looking at wont change inside beautifulsoup. If you are hoping to monitor your webrowser you would need a selenium type approach.